# Android Room: Get present database version / check if is out-dated

Tags: java, android, android-room

Say, I have a well-built room database in my app.

I planned to do a upgrade for the database. However, the upgrade / data migration is huge, thus I'd like to tell user to be patient, by displaying UI message, such as a `AlertDialog` or `Toast`, etc.

But I don't know how to check if message is needed to play ---- I mean, how do I get / check their present database version? Is there any function that works like `RoomDatabase.getVersion()`, or `RoomDatabase.isOlderVersion()` / `RoomDatabase.isOutDated()` ?

On the other hand, I know there's `Migration` class. Considering it was all I know that can check database version, I was planning to do like

> 1. Create Listener Holder in the Database.
> 2. Before UI Thread build the Database, register a listener in it.
> 3. When `Migration` is called, notify the listener to do things.

However, isn't it to complicated for a version upgrade? Any better idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all I recommend you to hide all migration in the background thread. It would be probably done anyway if the first access to the database in the app's lifecycle would be performed in the background.

Secondly, if you have any UI thread work with Database, please, try to change the logic of the app to put the access to Database in the background.

If you still need to check the version of the currently running Database this is the place you can get it:

`database.openHelper.writableDatabase.version`

OR

`database.openHelper.readableDatabase.version`

Database is the instance of your database you created earlier with the builder.

Btw, how you create the instance?

My question is probably about the automation of the process.

As for me, I create a database instance in the Dagger2. I have the provider method which calls builder. I add migrations there. Also, if the version of the existing database and the version of new database (after update) are different, the builder performs migrations I provide.

If you do all these actions manually, I hope you don't forget about anything.

**UPD:**

If you would like to know the version even without opening database, I would suggest the most simple way. Store the database version in the `Shared Preference`. Get it before building database instance, and perform whatever you would like to before starting the migration.

Comment: The app build a database instance when it's open, and close it when it's finished. I design to work like that since I think room instance is expensive, thus shall not stay in the background. Am I wrong about this? If so, I'd be glad to have one in the background.

Comment: @SamuelT.Chou The most expensive are the open and close actions. Keeping active connection with the database during the lifecycle of the app and even in the short time after the app is closed  (I mean was put into background by changing tasks) - it is OK. The connection to the database is like a lock and quick access to the file in the storage. It doesn't keep the whole file in the memory or anything like that.

Comment: And I do use the provider to deal with building and migration. If not, I'd have more question than this one lol

Comment: So, The main question here is: How to check the version of the database before database is opened? Right?

Comment: please let me figure it out -- which is more expensive, the database itself or the Dao it gives? Or neither of them is expensive? Memory is only occupied when Dao is doing CRUD? My room db holds thousands of data, I'm very concerned about the performance issue.

Comment: Dao is only the API to access the data in the database. It doesn't store the data itself. The most expensive is the Action `open`. I am not sure if the `close` action is the somehow same expensive. But I suppose that after close you would need to Open it again :) Under `Expensive` I mean it is time consuming. Not seconds. But still.

Comment: Yes. I'd like to know the version of the database before it is opened. Does `openHelper` works in this case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216484/discussion-between-samuel-t-chou-and-relaxedsoul).

Comment: It seems that `openHelper` isn't accessible after Room `v2.5.0-alpha02`

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin,

```
 helper = RoomHelper.getDatabase(applicationContext)
 val version = helper?.openHelper?.readableDatabase?.version
```